# Montoring & Event criteria

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm writing an application that monitors certain nodes in a network. Based on various conditions, every state of type of node can trigger an event. Now I want to enable the user to set criterias for monitoring & alerting.

Simple domain:

```
- Devices
    Any piece of hardware that can be accessed via ICMP (ping) and/or SNMP.

    * Is Discovered
    * Configuration Mismatch
    * Configuration changed
    * Is offline for
        10 minutes
        20 minutes
        1 day
        1 week
        ...

- User
    A registered user in my application environment

    * is registered
    * is removed
    * unathorized access event
```

I'm trying for hours now, but I can't figure out a domain model that adapts this type of flexible configuration. The simplest might be just to have certain base types 'TimeCriteria', 'EntityCriteria' that can be filled with key value pairs that are going to be validated against objects (their properties). Does anybody have a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but it *sounds* like a fit for the [Specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern). You can define a generic Specification interface like

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(T candidate);
}
```

Which will enable you to define various different concrete specifications, like

```
public class IsOfflineSpecification : ISpecification<Device>
{
    private readonly TimeSpan limit;

    public IsOfflineSpecification(TimeSpan limit)
    {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public IsSatisfiedBy(Device candidate)
    {
        // Compare candidate with limit here,
        // and return the appropriate answer (true/false)
    }
}
```

With the Specification pattern, you can also define [Composites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) that correspond to boolean **And**, **Or** and **Not** operations, etc.

Clients would talk to the Specification interface to figure out if a certain candidate fits the Specification:

```
ISpecification<Device> spec // ...
Device candidate = new //...
if (spec.IsSatisfiedBy(candidate))
    // do something interesting...
```